# How to display picture

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have some images which dynamically gets displayed on a web page.These images are clickable. When i click on one of the image I want to display another picture over the image that is clicked.If clicked again that picture needs to be removed.

Intially when the page loads the images will be displayed as shown below and when i click on these images another picture over the image which i have click should be displayed. As of now i am able to display the image on the side of the selected image. which is shown in the 2nd image

Comment: Please provide a simple working example using jsFiddle that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using jQuery, and you'll want all `<td>` to share the same class. In my example, I used `"dynamic-image"`.

HTML:

```
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td class="dynamic-image"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="dynamic-image"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="dynamic-image"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
    .dynamic-image {
        background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/h/N/y/5/p/empty-check-box-hi.png'); 
        background-size: contain; 
        position: relative; 
        height: 200px; 
        width: 200px; 
        content:" ";
    }
    .dynamic-image:before { content:" "; }
    .dynamic-image.active:before {
       background-image: url('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/niX/yoA/niXyoAbiB.png'); 
       background-size:contain; 
       height: 200px; 
       width: 200px; 
       position: absolute; 
       top: 0; 
    }
```

jQuery:

```
    $('.dynamic-image').click(function()
    { 
       $(this).toggleClass('active');  
    });
```

Check out my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdeang2/eyts25nh/1/

Comment: Here the image which is initially displayed is getting dissapperead. What i need is when i click on the image another image should display over the image which is already present. I should be able to see both the images. Its like marking attendance. Whenever i click on the image an 'X' should be displayed. When clicked again that 'X' should be disappear.

Comment: Nice answer @mdeang2 however John didn't include jQuery in their tags

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is just simply add two data attributes to your tr, so you can have data-image1 and data-image2 then simply change the img src when a mouse click happens.

Here is my jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wLvn8yzx/

Html

```
<img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-8.jpg" 
id="imageSwap" 
data-image1="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-8.jpg" 
data-image2="http://dressacat.com/chat.png">
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("imageSwap").onclick = function (e) {
    if (this.src == this.getAttribute("data-image1")) {
        this.src = this.getAttribute("data-image2");
    } else {
        this.src = this.getAttribute("data-image1");
    }
}
```

---

Or you could use classes and style them and set the background to the image. Here is another jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wLvn8yzx/1/

Html

```
<div id="imageSwap" class="image1"></div>
```

Css

```
div{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}

.image1{
    background-image: url("http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-8.jpg");
}

.image2{
    background-image: url("http://dressacat.com/chat.png");
}
```

Javacript

```
document.getElementById("imageSwap").onclick = function (e) {
    if (this.className == "image1") {
        this.className = "image2";
    } else {
       this.className = "image1";
    }
}
```

---

Update

I have created a new jsfiddle which uses a javascript function to hide and show the cross image.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wLvn8yzx/2/

Html

```
<img onclick="javascript:imageSwapper()" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/120px-Red.svg.png" class="imageSwap image1">
<img onclick="javascript:imageSwapper()" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/f/ff/20150316142725!Solid_blue.svg/120px-Solid_blue.svg.png" class="imageSwap image2">
<img onclick="javascript:imageSwapper()" src="https://s2.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/t/Green-Yellow_429842_i0.png" class="imageSwap image3">
<img id="crossImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Red_Cross.svg/120px-Red_Cross.svg.png" class="hidden">
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.show{
    display: inline;
}
```

Javascirpt

```
function imageSwapper() {
    var crossImage = document.getElementById("crossImage");
    if (crossImage.className == "hidden") {
        crossImage.className = "show";
    } else {
        crossImage.className = "hidden"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! What if a user wanted to change it from an image to a div display? For example; you have a list and you want to onclick button show a hidden div or table to show a line chart of your list, and on click again shows a column chart. Make sense?

Comment: @canvas :  Here the image which is initially displayed is getting dissapperead. What i need is when i click on the image another image should display over the image which is already present. I should be able to see both the images. Its like marking attendance. Whenever i click on the image an 'X' should be displayed. When clicked again that 'X' should be disappear.

Comment: @john Take a look at my updated answer at the bottom, Also Lzoesch that would be another question so I can't answer that here.